# Is the syntax for this SCSS function incorrect? Undefined operation error:

Tags: css, sass

@return ($page-width - $gap*($columns -1 ) / $columns)

the error says;

````
Error: Undefined operation: "1% times 8 -1".
        on line 14 of Users/amberjones/Desktop/Sass_Scss_first/sass-project/scss/partials/_functions.scss, in function `col-width`
        from line 15 of Users/amberjones/Desktop/Sass_Scss_first/sass-project/scss/partials/_variables.scss
        from line 2 of sass/Users/amberjones/Desktop/Sass_Scss_first/sass-project/scss/main.scss
>>   @return ($page-width - $gap*($columns -1 ) / $columns)```
````

Comment: THIS IS THE ACTUAL FUNCTION .                        ```@function col-width($columns: 12, $page-width: 100%, $gap: 1%) {
  @return ($page-width - $gap*($columns -1 ) / $columns)
};```

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be in _functions.scss in function `col-width`.
Cannot multiply percentage and integers.
You have to convert all into integers and then use the function `percentage()` to convert again:
[percentage function](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/functions/math#percentage)

The operations are allowed only for integers